# Programa Travando no While

Tags: java, while

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e estou tendo problemas com o mesmo, este programa que estou postando é símiliar ao que estou trabalhando.

O problema é o seguinte: chega no `while`, o programa faz sua função, depois trava e não sai.

Já tentei de tudo. Alguém poderia dar alguma sugestão?

```
public class CommandZ {

private static String Command;
private static Scanner scan;


public static void main(String[] args) {        
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Shell: ");
        Command = scan.nextLine();

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell.exe", "-Command", Command);
        Process p;
        try {
            p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start powershell");
            return;
        }


        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        System.out.println("Begin!");
        try {
            //PROBLEMA AQUI
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                //Imprimi as linhas, e não da sequência no programa..




            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read line");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Exit");


    }
```

Comment: Já tentou isolar o problema? provavelmente esse `InputStreamReader` é que está pendurando. Acho que você não consegue lê-lo da forma como está tentando. Ou talvez você precisa finalizar esse processo para terminar o *stream*. Eu nunca fiz nada parecido. Isso foi ideia sua? Você leu em algum lugar que dá para fazer isto? Qualquer informação adicional pode ajudar.

Comment: eu estou tentando fazer tipo um framework pra interagir com o prompt do windows, mais estou com esse problema, e nao consigo dar sequência no programa..

tentei um bufferedReader.close depois do while..
não funcionou..

Comment: Eu tenho dúvidas se o que você está tentando fazer é possível, pelo menos desta forma. É óbvio que se está pendurado no `while` qualquer tentativa de fazer algo depois dela, não será realizada. E duvido que tentar fechar o *stream* dentro do `while` também seja a solução. Mesmo que pareça funcionar isso cheira muito mal.

Comment: fechar o stream dentro do while, ele ira lêr apenas a primeira linha, e o resto ja era..
será que não tem outro jeito então de fazer isso ?

Comment: Já tentei, da um close depois do while, ele nem sequer chegou lá...

Comment: tá osso.. nada adianta... um gringo falou que eu precisava de outra thread pra lêr o output e depois adicionar ela no final do metodo main()

Comment: É provável que tenha outra solução mas precisa ter profundo conhecimento de todas as APIs que interagem com processos e *streams*, talvez ter um sistema de notificação quando há algo novo no *stream* e responder para esta sinalização ao invés de ficar em *loop*. Acho que o seu problema é mais embaixo, espero que alguém possa dar alguma ideia de fazer diferente mas não acho que o problema seja só o `while`. E *thread* sozinha não vai resolver nada, tem que ver como usar de um jeito correto (se é que vai ajudar).

Comment: Eu não uso windows, testo em VirtualMachine,  porém fiz um teste em um outro computador com windows 7 e o problema foi o mesmo...

Comment: Ele lê tudo, toda a saida do prompt.. porém ao finalizar, ele para o programa

Comment: tentei as sugestões, o problema permanece.. :P

Comment: Bom, vamos aguardar pra ver se alguem com mais experienca em Java aparece com um caminho (domingo a coisa fica mais devagar...).

Comment: hehe, sim  Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

Este código consegue resolver o teu problema.

A fonte é desta [conversa](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2331965?start=0&tstart=0), especificamente no fim da conversa.

Codigo:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class Gobbler implements Runnable {

    private PrintStream out;
    private String message;

    private BufferedReader reader;

    public Gobbler(InputStream inputStream, PrintStream out) {
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
               this.out = out;
        this.message = ( null != message ) ? message : "";
    }

    public void run() {
        String line;

        try {
            while (null != (line = this.reader.readLine())) {
                out.println(message + line);
            }
            this.reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


class PowerConsole {

    private ProcessBuilder pb;
    Process p;
    boolean closed = false;
    PrintWriter writer;

    PowerConsole(String[] commandList) {
        pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandList);
        try {
            p = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot execute PowerShell.exe", ex);
        }
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(p.getOutputStream())), true);
        Gobbler outGobbler = new Gobbler(p.getInputStream(), System.out);
        Gobbler errGobbler = new Gobbler(p.getErrorStream(), System.out);
        Thread outThread = new Thread(outGobbler);
        Thread errThread = new Thread(errGobbler);
        outThread.start();
        errThread.start();
    }

    public void execute(String command) {
        if (!closed) {
            writer.println(command);
            writer.flush();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Power console has ben closed.");
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            execute("exit");
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        PowerConsole pc = new PowerConsole(new String[]{"powershell.exe", "-NoExit", "-Command", "-"});
        System.out.println("========== Executing dir");
        pc.execute("dir"); 
//        System.out.println("========== Executing cd\\");
//        pc.execute("cd \\"); Thread.sleep(2000);
//        System.out.println("========== Executing dir");
//        pc.execute("dir"); Thread.sleep(2000);
//        System.out.println("========== Executing cd \\temp");
//        pc.execute("cd \\temp"); Thread.sleep(2000);
//        System.out.println("========== Executing dir");
//        pc.execute("dir"); Thread.sleep(2000);
//        System.out.println("========== Executing cd \\bubba");
//        pc.execute("cd \\bubba"); Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("========== Exiting .... bye.");
        pc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma solução no [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com):

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(
                "powershell.exe", "-Command", Command);
        proc.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = proc.start();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: Você pode postar a sua solução sem problemas, mas a parte que você faz uma nova pergunta não é apropriado. O ideal seria você criar uma nova pergunta e se for necessário linkar essa daqui para maior entendimento.

Comment: Estou removendo a nova pergunta daqui, ok? Se quiser pode postar uma nova separadamente. O conteúdo que retirei está disponível no [histórico de edição](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/37491/revisions).

Comment: Tudo bem!
eu já fiz uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o seu problema é porque o "powershell.exe" esta esperando comando em runtime.
E por causa disso o while "trava" na execução. Porque o Process está esperando novas dados para serem lidos.

Encontrei este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253614/execute-a-shell-command-using-processbuilder-and-interact-with-it) que fala sobre isso.

Também realizei alguns teste executando no Windows.
Chamando o cmd.exe e passando os comandos, o mesmo trava no while. Pois imagino que ele esteja esperando novos comandos para continuar retornando no InputStreamReader.
Porém quando executo apenas um comando como ipconfig. Ele finaliza o programa normalmente.

Bom eu espero ter ajudado ^^

Answer (score -2):

O teu erro tem haver com lógica. Você não garantiu que a variável `line` alcance o valor `null` por isso o `while` repete indefinidamente. Deves fazer isso no fim do `while`, adicionei antes do comentário:

```
...
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
    line = null;
 //Imprimi as linhas, e não da sequência no programa..
...
```

Comment: Isso equivale mais ou menos a botar um `break` sem condição ali. Não creio que seja o que o OP quer. Caso contrário, não precisava nem de while.

Comment: Deste jeito será executada apenas uma interação. Seria bom colocar o fecho do bloco do ciclo `while` para perceber melhor @HeidyMiguel.

Comment: @Heydy Miguel   Você só ta esquecendo que se colocar um line = null dentro do while, o código nao roda mais,
pq ele imprimi linha por linha do comando do prompt, na tela do usuario então cada linha é uma nova saida,  colocando esse null ele irá imprimir apenas uma linha sacou?